# Como usar los Join

Tags: sql, join, pgadmin

Hola ¿Qué tal? estoy comezando a practicar SQL y me surge la siguiente duda que no puedo resolver.
Quiero crear una `VIEW` en donde me muestre la columna `pasaporte_quien_reciba` **(foto 1)** de aquellas filas en donde `boleta_comprador` = falso y `precio_boleta` > 2500 **(de la tabla de la foto 2)**. Quisiera mantener la tabla 2 y agregar de la tabla 1 lo similar y la columna `pasaporte_quien_reciba`.
Llave foránea = `id_boleta`.

Tabla 1, intercambio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla 2, compra_boleta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que yo realice, quisiera que aparezcan los datos de la tabla dos también.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias, acepto cualquier sugerencia o tip.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Incluye tu trabajo y los errores asociados, en tu pregunta. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).